# Why would PHP json_encode not returning the correct value from passed in array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, integer

all. I am working on a custom-build API built in PHP. I have an array (see below) that has been returned from my database access object. When I use the `json_encode` function, the int value assigned to phone1Type gets encoded incorrectly. I have tried this with multiple records, and the value in the encoded json object always matches the phone2Type. Any ideas as to what might be going on? (I've included two sample arrays below in addition to their corresponding json object.)

The code that I'm using to check the array and json values is the following:

```
$responseObject = $userCtrl->selectPersonForUserId($userId);
var_dump($responseObject);
var_dump(json_encode($responseObject));
```

One example array to encode is as follows. (The phone1Type and phone2Type keys are at the very end, but include the full array here for completeness. Also, as a side note, the other int values in the array are encoding fine.)

```
object(Adult)#13 (8) {
  ["person":protected]=>
  object(Person)#14 (4) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    int(3)
    ["firstName":protected]=>
    string(7) "William"
    ["lastName":protected]=>
    string(3) "Smith"
    ["hasVerified":protected]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["address":protected]=>
  object(Address)#17 (4) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    int(2)
    ["address1":protected]=>
    string(15) "520 Hilbert Dr."
    ["address2":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["city":protected]=>
    object(City)#18 (3) {
      ["zip":protected]=>
      string(5) "71342"
      ["city":protected]=>
      string(11) "West Monroe"
      ["state":protected]=>
      string(2) "AL"
    }
  }
  ["email":protected]=>
  string(14) "wmrmay@spam.com"
  ["phone1":protected]=>
  string(10) "6195080000"
  ["phone1Type":protected]=>
  int(1)
  ["phone2":protected]=>
  string(10) "3188126574"
  ["phone2Type":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["teacher":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

This encodes to the following json object:

```
{"person":{"id":3,"firstName":"William","lastName":"Smith","hasVerified":false},"address":{"id":2,"address1":"520 Hilbert Dr.","address2":"","city":{"zip":"71342","city":"West Monroe","state":"AL"}},"email":"wmrmay@spam.com","phone1":"6195080000","phone1Type":0,"phone2":"3188126574","phone2Type":0,"teacher":null}
```

For brevity, here's the last few lines of another array followed by its json counterpart:

```
  ["email":protected]=>
  string(20) "wltrallen2@gmail.com"
  ["phone1":protected]=>
  string(10) "6192047586"
  ["phone1Type":protected]=>
  int(1)
  ["phone2":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["phone2Type":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["teacher":protected]=>
  NULL
```

```
"email":"wltrallen2@gmail.com","phone1":"6192047586","phone1Type":null,"phone2":null,"phone2Type":null,"teacher":null}
```

Edited to add original Adult.php model class:

```
class Adult implements JsonSerializable {
    protected $person; // Person object
    protected $address; // Address object
    protected $email;
    protected $phone1;
    protected $phone1Type; // PhoneType object
    protected $phone2;
    protected $phone2Type; // PhoneType object
    protected $teacher; // Teacher object

    public function __construct($person, $address, $email, $phone1, $phone1Type, $phone2, $phone2Type, $teacher)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone1 = $phone1;
        $this->phone1Type = $phone1Type;
        $this->phone2 = $phone2;
        $this->phone2Type = $phone2Type;
        $this->teacher = $teacher;
    }

... // Getters and Setters removed for brevity

    private function getPhoneType($type) {
     if(PhoneTypes::isValid($type)) {
          return PhoneTypes::StringDict[$type];
        }

        return '';
    }
    
    function jsonSerialize() {
     $array = [
       'person' => $this->person,
       'address' => $this->address,
       'email' => $this->email,
       'phone1' => $this->phone1,
       'phone1Type' => $this->phone2Type,
       'phone2' => $this->phone2,
       'phone2Type' => $this->phone2Type,
       'teacher' => $this->teacher
     ];
 
     return $array;
   } 
}
```

Comment: How is the field `phone1Type` declared in the class? Can you post the source of the `Adult` class?

Comment: `"phone1Type":0` isn't a boolean. A boolean would be `"phone1Type":false`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, you are correct. I misstated the case. Thank you for pointing that out and having me go back and look. I will edit the question.

Comment: @AterLux, I actually found my mistake. I will post a response below, and you are correct. The mistake was in the model class for Adult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, embarrassingly, this was just caused by an initial typo and then forgetfulness on my part.

1. In the Adult.php model class, I has implemented the `JsonSerializable` interface to make sure that an Adult object could be encoded in Json. When doing so, I made a typographical error when building the array:

```
       'phone1Type' => $this->phone2Type,
```

which should have been, of course...

```
       'phone1Type' => $this->phone1Type,
```

This typo was the source of my issue. Ugh!

2. However, as I've been deeply mired in this project and it had been some time since I originally built those model classes, I had completely forgot that for an object to be encodable by JSON that it had to implement the `JsonSerializable` interface. So, as I was debugging, it never occurred to me to look back in my model at the very end of the file to examine the `jsonSerialize()` function. (Insert face palm here.)

Thank you for your responses. This is the first time that I've actually gotten to post a question on stackOverflow, and I appreciate you all taking a look. Sorry that it wasn't an exciting question and merely a silly novice programmer moment.